# adding active class to menu with php doesn't work when contents are loading with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i have a trouble to add active class of current page to my menu with php. since i used `jquery bbq` [jquery bbq](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)which is a plugin on `html5 history api` to load pages dynamically with ajax although it loads pages normally but i want to add active class to current page. already tried different methods with jquery but failed and also this php code doesn't bring any joy for me.

here is code.

**navigation with php code**

```
   <?php 
     $Browse_Page0="menu-items";
     $Top_albums_Page0="menu-items";
     $Top_artists_Page0="menu-items";
     $Top_lists_Page0="menu-items";
     $Charts_Page0="menu-items";

     //php function for active vertical menu current state
     $menuLinkid=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],".php");
     if($menuLinkid=="Browse_Page0"){
     $Browse_Page0='active';
     }else if ($menuLinkid=="Top_albums_Page0"){
     $Top_albums_Page0='active';
     }else if ($menuLinkid=="Top_artists_Page0"){
     $Top_artists_Page0='active';
     }else if ($menuLinkid=="Top_lists_Page0"){
     $Top_lists_Page0='active';
     }else if ($menuLinkid=="Charts_Page0"){
     $Charts_Page0='active';
     }
   ?>
  <div id="vertical-menu">
        <!--<h2 class="logo">LOGO</h2>-->
        <div class="logo">
        <span class="arcd-male97"></span> 
        <h2 class="logo-name">AMR</h2>
        <h6 class="logo-desc">ARCADE MUSIC REPOSITORY</h6>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul id='menu' class="tabs menu-items">

                <li><a class="<?php echo $Browse_Page0; ?>" href="#Browse/Browse_Page0.php"><i class="arcd-archive"></i></br>Browse</a></li>
                <li><a class="<?php echo $Top_albums_Page0; ?>" href="#Top_albums/Top_albums_Page0.php"><i class="arcd-music97"></i></br>Top albums</a></li>
                <li><a class="<?php echo $Top_artists_Page0; ?>" href="#Top_artists/Top_artists_Page0.php" ><i class="arcd-microphone52"></i></br>Top artists</a></li>
                <li><a class="<?php echo $Top_lists_Page0; ?>" href="#Top_lists/Top_lists_Page0.php" ><i class="arcd-numbered8"></i></br>Top lists</a></li>
                <li><a class="<?php echo $Charts_Page0; ?>" href="#Charts/Charts_Page0.php" ><i class="arcd-rising9"></i></br>Charts</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
     </div>
```

**secondary navigation menu**

```
  <nav>
     <ul id="tabnav">
        <li class="pop_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page1.php"><i class="arcd-microphone352"></i>pop</a></li>
        <li class="country_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page2.php"><i class="arcd-guitarcountry"></i>country</a></li>
        <li class="rock_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page3.php"><i class="arcd-electricclone"></i>rock</a></li>
        <li class="blues_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page4.php"><i class="arcd-harmonicblues"></i>blues</a></li>
        <li class="edm_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page5.php"><i class="arcd-disc62edm"></i>edm</a></li>
        <li class="jazz_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page6.php"><i class="arcd-trumpet12jazz"></i>jazz</a></li>
        <li class="rnb_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page7.php"><i class="arcd-mic102"></i>r&b</a></li>
        <li class="hip-hop_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page8.php"><i class="arcd-musicplayer1hiphop"></i>hip hop</a></li>
        <li class="reggae_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page9.php"><i class="arcd-mic102"></i>reggae</a></li>
        <li class="classical_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page10.php"><i class="arcd-violin62classical"></i>classical</a></li>
        <li class="folk_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page11.php"><i class="arcd-guitar92folk"></i>folk</a></li>
        <li class="soul_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page12.php"><i class="arcd-mic102"></i>soul</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
```

i hope someone can help me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
    $("#menu .active").removeClass("active");
    $("#menu a[href=\"" + location.hash + "\"]").addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: thanks for ans. but its not working on my secondary navigation!